# Ruby on Rails: link_to :remote=> true still navigating.

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to, link-to-remote

I'm new to rails, and I'm trying to perform an ajax request. Correct me if I'm wrong, but as I understand it, requests are supposed to be performed with a link_to using :remote true.

I have this line of code, which links to the desired page:

```
    link_to 'Log Out',{:controller=>"ajax_handlers", :action=>"logout"}, :class=>'navButton', :remote=>true
```

But when I click the link it still navigates to the log out page. I have seen other posts suggesting that this is caused by a syntax error which causes :remote => true to be added to the url as a query parameter. However, the html renders to this:

```
    <a href="/logout" class="navButton" data-remote="true">Log Out</a>
```

Which to me looks like it should be working.

A final note: I've seen posts saying that they can't get this working because of some problem with jQuery configuration. However, I am not using jQuery (it could be a javascript configuration error, but I don't know).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 3, `:remote => true` necessarily requires jQuery and jquery-ujs. You'll need to load them in order to get the functionality you're seeking, even if you don't ever end up using jQuery.

Assuming you're on Rails >3.1, you're using the asset pipeline. By default, the `application.js` manifest file will load all the files you need. Include the `application.js` file by adding the following tag to your `application.html.erb` layout:

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
```